# Android : Getting email message with gmail-api

Tags: android, gmail-api

I am getting a message in raw format . Then got the Mimemessage by

```
MimeMessage email = new MimeMessage(session, new ByteArrayInputStream(emailBytes));
```

Now email.getSubject is returning right value but
email.getReceivedDate is null

Please explain this behaviour. Is this the right way to decode different parts of the mail

```
com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Message fullMessage = mService.users().messages().get(acct.sEmail, message.getId()).setFormat("raw").execute();
                Properties props = new Properties();
                idg.javax.mail.Session session = idg.javax.mail.Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

                byte[] emailBytes = com.google.api.client.util.Base64.decodeBase64(fullMessage.getRaw());
                try {
                    idg.javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage email = new idg.javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage(session, new ByteArrayInputStream(emailBytes));
                    Log.i("Received date","is" + email.getReceivedDate() + message.getId());
                    Log.i("subject", "is" + email.getSubject());

                } catch (MessagingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use `getReceivedDate()` for `MimeMessage` and yes, ofcourse its the better way to retrieve the values for different parts of mail.

This is to retrieve `MimeMessage`:
[Users MimeMessage](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get)

This is to get Different Properties of mail :[MimeMessage Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html)

Comment: then why it is returned as null .

Comment: I have added the code how i am doing it. I suspect i am not doing it the right way.